# New Smart Folder keyboard shortcut doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut, smart-folders

For some reason the keyboard shortcut for New Smart Folder doesn't work for me in Finder and I can't figure out why.  I have quit every program I use that can modify shortcuts - Alfred2, BetterTouchTool, TotalFinder, and PathFinder.  Still, CMD-Shift-N does absolutely nothing in Finder.  Selecting from the File Menu manually works fine, but the shortcut refuses to do anything.

I've also checked in the System Prefs in case there was a rogue shortcut mapped to the same keystroke there, but there is not.

How can I figure out what is preventing this shortcut from working?  I've also seen other shortcuts refuse to work for reasons unknown so I'd love to really get to the bottom of this.

Comment: As it stands, there's not enough detail for us to help you. Pictures of your Finder edit menu would help, showing at least that the key command is there. That would also help us see precisely *what* command you're trying to invoke it with. Your myriad 3rd party tools is not going to help; you may need to test on a new account, or even uninstall your plethora of 'helpers' to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: There's nothing special about the File menu (not Edit).  It contains all the normal things, including `New Smart Folder` with the default key command next to it.  I will boot in safe mode and see if anything changes and troubleshoot from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found it.  Turns out it was a program I didn't even realize HAD shortcut keys - eNounce MySpeed.  Turned them off since I never use them anyway and now all my shortcuts work correctly again.  What a relief.